# Vertical align in beamer frames in LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am trying to vertically align content inside a *single* beamer frame.
On the manual I've found the `[t]` option to add to `\begin{frame}`.

Question is, how do I add that option in LyX?

I have tried with ERT in the frame title or using Short Title option without success.

Also, I have tried using directly ERT to define the frame, something like:

```
ERT \begin{frame}[t]
ERT \frametitle{Foo Bar}

normal LyX content here

ERT \end{frame}
```

but no success again.

How do I do something like that?

Comment: I think this might fall under the improvements that @JSpitzm has implemented recently, which will make it into LyX 2.1. If you're using Ubuntu you can try it out now with the PPA: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu . I know there is some documentation on these Beamer improvements and the Beamer examples are reworked. But I'm not sure these improvements fix what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERT was fine, probably I just misplaced it.

For future reference, insert it between the frame and the frame title:

```
Frame <ert>[t]</ert>Title here
```

EDIT: Does not work with Plain frames, though...